# Ethereum node stuck can't sync on Win. 8.1

Tags: wallets, ether, synchronization, nodes

I've downloaded the latest version but can't make the Ethereum node sync. It just states:  `Ethereum node needs to sync.. Please wait` . I've also turned my firewall off but still not working. Plus I also deleted the /chaindata folder in windows explorer and still not working! Can anyone help? I'm not a techie guy. Thanks.